# Norm preserving matrices also preserve inner products

Tags: lie-groups

I am trying to prove that if $A \in M_n(\mathbb C)$ preserves norms then it also preserves inner products. I showed this for real matrices and I want to use this for this proof here. Let $f_n: \mathbb C^n \to \mathbb R^{2n}$ be the map $(x_1 + iy_2, x_2 + iy_2, \dots) \mapsto (x_1,x_2, \dots, y_1, y_2, \dots) $ and let $\rho_n: M_n(\mathbb C) \to M_{2n}(\mathbb R)$ be the homomorphism

$$ X + iY \mapsto \left ( \begin{array}{cc} 
X & Y \\
-Y & X
\end{array}\right )$$

Let $A = X + iY$ preserve norms. Note that $R_A = f^{-1}_n \circ R_{\rho_n(A)}\circ f_n$ hence $f^{-1}_n \circ R_{\rho_n(A)}\circ f_n$ preserves norms. By the result for real matrices $f^{-1}_n \circ R_{\rho_n(A)}\circ f_n$ therefore also preserves inner products:

$$ \langle X, Y\rangle = \langle f_n^{-1}(R_{\rho_n(A)}(f_n(X)), f_n^{-1}(R_{\rho_n(A)}(f_n(Y))\rangle$$

And this is where I got stuck. How can I show that $ \langle X, Y\rangle  =  \langle R_A(X), R_A(Y)\rangle $ from here?

Comment: Why not use the [polarization identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity#For_vector_spaces_with_complex_scalars)?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis That is a good point. Thank you, I think I can use it!

Comment: Hm... but the book states that this doesn't work. It's on page 38 in  [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=Un_15Im3NhUC&lpg=PP1&hl=ja&pg=PA36#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: Perhaps the author means it doesn't work using the exact same formula - the identity is more complicated in the complex case.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis But is there a polarisation identity for quaternions?